# How to add an external appliance into the middle of a lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, lighting, exterior, uk

The previous owner of my house spliced the downstairs lighting circuit to power some outdoor heaters. They ran the twin and earth cable **through the exterior wall**, and wired it into an external switch to control the heaters. It was a terrible mess, I didn't trust it at all, and I didn't want the heaters anyway. So I've decommissioned the whole lot, and have temporarily spliced the lighting circuit back together inside a weatherproof junction box.

I'm now thinking I'd like to make use of this point to add a security light, but I want to do it properly.

What I have is a loop of cable coming out of the wall, about a metre long. (50cm up to the junction box, and back down again). My feeling is to replace the junction box with a fused connection unit ([like this one](https://www.bgelectrical.uk/uk/wiring-devices/weatherproof-storm/fused-connection-unit)). The security light doesn't really need a switch as it has a sensor, but I figured this was preferable to just wiring the security light into the junction box, and I wasn't sure exactly how to wire it in either.

If I use a connection unit like this, would I simply wire both of the cut ends of the original circuit into the supply terminals?

What would the preferred approach be? What else should I consider?

Comment: Make sure that the wiring used for the exterior run is approved for wet locations. Appropriate wet-location wire ratings are called for by the NEC in the US, and I'm sure the UK has equivalents.

Comment: "replace the junction box with a fused connection unit" - why? J-box has power and a neutral, right? Just hang the light. "I wasn't sure exactly how to wire it in either." - uh... then we're done here.

Comment: @mazua could you post as your answer how to wire this without the need for the fused connection unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks appropriate.  But when you say "simply wire both of the cut ends of the original circuit into the supply terminals", you cannot just cram multiple wires into a terminal meant for one.  Look up the proper method of splicing wires, and the minimum box size required for the number of wires, splices, and so forth, and then choose a box large enough to accommodate them all.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps one small box to join the cut ends, then a single power cable to the outdoor fuse? Otherwise I'm looking at a pretty big box to house it all together

Comment: For the linked connection unit, multiple wires can be secured in a single terminal. The spec says "Terminal Capacity: 3 x 2.5mm2", meaning each terminal can secure 3 wires each of cross section up to 2.5mm2. Standard on a lighting circuit will be 1.5mm2, so fitting 2 will be no problem. This is standard for UK units

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the twin and earth cables might be 1.0mm. Painted over, but some similar width cable I have says "2x1.0+1.0"

Comment: @rhellen good catch.  The more I learn about Euro wiring practices, the more I like.